# How to use configuration from dotnet 6 minimal API in Entity Framework Core cli tools

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, .net-6.0

I'm trying to build an API with EF Core as database access, right now on dotnet 6 RC1. I want to use dotnet cli tools to manage migrations (creating, updating the database etc), but the tools do not cooperate with minimal API from the template.

Here is my Program.cs:

```
void ConfigureApp(WebApplication webApplication)
{
    // Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    if (webApplication.Environment.IsDevelopment())
    {
        webApplication.UseSwagger();
        webApplication.UseSwaggerUI(c => c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "Eyespert.Server v1"));
    }

    webApplication.UseHttpsRedirection();

    webApplication.UseAuthentication();
    webApplication.UseAuthorization();

    webApplication.MapControllers();
}

void RegisterServices(WebApplicationBuilder builder)
{
    builder.Services.AddControllers();
    builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
    {
        c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new() { Title = "App", Version = "v1" });
    });
    
    builder.Services.AddDbContext<MyContext>(opt =>
    {
        string connectionString = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("MyConnectionString");
        opt.UseNpgsql(connectionString);
    });
}

WebApplicationBuilder builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

RegisterServices(builder);

WebApplication app = builder.Build();

ConfigureApp(app);

app.Run();
```

If that code was using the Program/Startup class combo and old builders, I could type in console `dotnet ef migrations add InitialCreate` and the tool would read appsettings.development.json (even though it's different project than the context) and run the migration on proper database. With minimal API style this is not the case.

As a solution, I made a design time context factory:

```
public class DesignTimeDbContextFactory : IDesignTimeDbContextFactory<MyContext>
    {
        public MyContextCreateDbContext(string[] args)
        {
            DbContextOptionsBuilder<MyContext> dbContextOptionsBuilder =
                new();

            dbContextOptionsBuilder.UseNpgsql(@"myconnectionstring");

            Console.WriteLine("Creating default MyContext");
            
            return new MyContext(dbContextOptionsBuilder.Options);
        }
    }
```

As you can see, I hardcoded the connection string. I know that I can construct the `ConfigurationBuilder` and use relative paths to find the correct json file and use it to find the connection string, but it feels like a dirty hack.

What would THE way to do it with dotnet 6?

Comment: *"What would THE way to do it with dotnet 6?"* There is no such thing as net6 and EFC6 at this time. Just some previews, RCs or whatever they call them. The important is that they are not released. So you can't expect documentation or EFC tools working etc. When they release it, most probably they'll update the docs for the [supported Design-time DbContext Creation patterns](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/cli/dbcontext-creation?tabs=dotnet-core-cli) if any. Until then, just use what you have.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I created an MinimalAPI project using EFCore Context and it runs fine no major problem ocourred, other than updating ef tools cli and so on, see the complete project:

**MinimalApi.csproj**

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <LangVersion>Preview</LangVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" Version="6.0.0-rc.1.21452.10">
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="6.0.0-rc.1.21452.10">
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Swashbuckle.AspNetCore" Version="6.1.5" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\Infra\Infra.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

**Program.cs**

```
using Infra;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddDbContext<Context>(opts =>
{
    var connString = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("MyConnectionString");
    opts.UseSqlServer(connString, options =>
    {
        options.MigrationsAssembly(typeof(Context).Assembly.FullName.Split(',')[0]);
    });
});

await using var app = builder.Build();

if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
}

app.MapGet("/", (Func<string>)(() => "Hello World!"));

await app.RunAsync();
```

**Infra.csproj**

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <LangVersion>Preview</LangVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="6.0.0-rc.1.21452.10" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" Version="6.0.0-rc.1.21452.10">
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="6.0.0-rc.1.21452.10" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="6.0.0-rc.1.21452.10">
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
    </PackageReference>
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\Domain\Domain.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

**Infra.Context.cs**

```
using Domain;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace Infra
{
    public class Context : DbContext
    {

        public Context(DbContextOptions options) : base(options)
        {
        }

        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
        }

        public DbSet<MyEntity> MyEntities { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**Domain.csproj**

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <LangVersion>Preview</LangVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>

</Project>
```

**Entity example (MyEntity.cs)**

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

namespace Domain
{
    public class MyEntity
    {
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Value { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**Creating migration on nuget package manager**

```
PM> Add-Migration InitialMigration
Build started...
Build succeeded.
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure[10403]
      Entity Framework Core 6.0.0-rc.1.21452.10 initialized 'Context' using provider 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer:6.0.0-rc.1.21452.10' with options: MigrationsAssembly=Infra
```

**updating database on nuget package manager**

```
PM> Update-Database
Build started...
Build succeeded.
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure[10403]
      Entity Framework Core 6.0.0-rc.1.21452.10 initialized 'Context' using provider 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer:6.0.0-rc.1.21452.10' with options: MigrationsAssembly=Infra 
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20101]
      Executed DbCommand (2,338ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='60']
      CREATE DATABASE [MinimalApiDb];
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20101]
      Executed DbCommand (933ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='60']
      IF SERVERPROPERTY('EngineEdition') <> 5
      BEGIN
          ALTER DATABASE [MinimalApiDb] SET READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT ON;
      END;
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20101]
      Executed DbCommand (29ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
      SELECT 1
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20101]
      Executed DbCommand (18ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
      CREATE TABLE [__EFMigrationsHistory] (
          [MigrationId] nvarchar(150) NOT NULL,
          [ProductVersion] nvarchar(32) NOT NULL,
          CONSTRAINT [PK___EFMigrationsHistory] PRIMARY KEY ([MigrationId])
      );
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20101]
      Executed DbCommand (3ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
      SELECT 1
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20101]
      Executed DbCommand (17ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
      SELECT OBJECT_ID(N'[__EFMigrationsHistory]');
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20101]
      Executed DbCommand (5ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
      SELECT [MigrationId], [ProductVersion]
      FROM [__EFMigrationsHistory]
      ORDER BY [MigrationId];
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations[20402]
      Applying migration '20211001150743_InitialMigration'.
Applying migration '20211001150743_InitialMigration'.
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20101]
      Executed DbCommand (176ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
      CREATE TABLE [MyEntities] (
          [Id] uniqueidentifier NOT NULL,
          [Name] nvarchar(max) NOT NULL,
          [Value] nvarchar(max) NOT NULL,
          CONSTRAINT [PK_MyEntities] PRIMARY KEY ([Id])
      );
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20101]
      Executed DbCommand (23ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
      INSERT INTO [__EFMigrationsHistory] ([MigrationId], [ProductVersion])
      VALUES (N'20211001150743_InitialMigration', N'6.0.0-rc.1.21452.10');
Done.
PM>
```

**To use dotnet ef tools you will  need to update to the latest rc to match your projetc designer/tools**

```
dotnet tool update --global dotnet-ef --version 6.0.0-rc.1.21452.10
```

- Note that is the same version of package you are using in the project packages

**Creating a migration via ef tools cli**

```
PS D:\Repositorios\MinimalApi\MinimalApi> dotnet ef migrations add eftoolsmigration -s "D:\Repositorios\MinimalApi\MinimalApi\MinimalApi.csproj" -p "D:\Repositorios\MinimalApi\Infra\Infra.csproj"
```

```
Build started...
Build succeeded.
info: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure[10403]
      Entity Framework Core 6.0.0-rc.1.21452.10 initialized 'Context' using provider 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer:6.0.0-rc.1.21452.10' with options: MigrationsAssembly=Infra
Done. To undo this action, use 'ef migrations remove'
PS D:\Repositorios\MinimalApi\MinimalApi>
```

**Updating database via ef tools cli**

```
 dotnet ef database update -s "D:\Repositorios\MinimalApi\MinimalApi\MinimalApi.csproj" -p "D:\Repositorios\MinimalApi\Infra\Infra.csproj"
```

- Note that -s is your Startup project path;
- Note that -p is your target project path (where context is configured);

**Automatically created Migrations folder**

[image: Automatically created Migrations folder]

**Final project structure**

[image: Final project structure]

**Created database**

[image: Created database]

- Note that you will have to set "include prerelease" on you package manager to get the versions compatibles with .Net 6
- Note tha you are using Postgree DB, it will have to have a client compatible with EF Core 6.xxx

**Runtimes and SDKs intalled (.NET 6 only for clarity)**

```
PS C:\Users\Daniel> dotnet --list-runtimes
Microsoft.NETCore.App 6.0.0-rc.1.21451.13 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 6.0.0-rc.1.21451.3 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]

PS C:\Users\Daniel> dotnet --list-sdks
6.0.100-rc.1.21463.6 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
```

Comment: I was missing the `-p` and `-s` switches on the cli tool invocation, thanks a lot!

Comment: Since other people start asking the same question (e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69474533/asp-net-6-new-programcs-structure-and-initialising-the-identity-entityframewo), before redirecting them here I'm obliged to ask if someone can confirm this **really** works (I can't  pollute my production environment with MS experiments) which is highly doubtful. All this boilerplate, including `-p` and `-s` options is not new and has nothing to do with minimal API. SqlServer and MinimalApiDb just sound like "reasonable default".

Comment: The only prove would be if you hardcode `.UseSomeDb(...)` with hardcoded  "MyFooBar" db name, a string which doesn't follow any naming convention or configuration source, and the tool creates/updates such database. Which logically and technically I don't see how could happen (except somehow they use Roslyn to really analyze your **source code** and extract the `DbContext` configuration code). With the "old" approach, they search (with reflection) for a specific static method, and **execute* it in order to get configured `DbContext` instance from DI.

Comment: I think the trick is also in `<LangVersion>Preview</LangVersion>`, because the runtime has to recognize the main `Program.cs` as a static class with main method, and somehow extract the builder (not sure how it works)

Comment: This answer is really clear and complete. Talking about ef tools, I don't like that you have to install the vendor-related packages into the Infra project which could be  agnostic to this.

Comment: actually, i had to install it because in that time the Package-Manager console was not ready to deal with minimal APIs, today you can use normally inside visual studio with no further problems :)