# ASP.NET Core 6, new "Programcs" structure and initialising the Identity Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, microsoft-identity-platform, asp.net-core-6.0

I was following [this ASP.NET Core 5 + SQL Server tutorial](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/authentication-and-authorization-in-asp-net-5-with-jwt-and-swagger/) but with ASP.NET Core 6 + Sqlite. The tutorial says that I should run `add-migration Initial` in the package manager, but if I do that, I get

> Unable to create an object of type 'ApplicationDbContext'. For the different patterns supported at design time, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=851728

I have searched the web and found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65944650/455796) which says that I should use the traditional namespace/class/`static Main()` structure instead of the "top-level code feature". But that was the default `Program.cs` code that Visual Studio 2022 generated for the project.

It is absurd that I have to change the default project structure that MS created to use MS's database framework. How can I initialise the database without changing the `Program.cs` structure to the old one?

Program.cs

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens;
using System.Text;
using WebApplication1.Authentication;
using Microsoft.OpenApi.Models;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.

builder.Services.AddControllers();

builder.Services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>();
builder.Services.AddEntityFrameworkSqlite().AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>();

builder.Services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>()
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
    .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

builder.Services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.DefaultScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
}).AddJwtBearer(options =>
{...
```

ApplicationDbContext.cs

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace WebApplication1.Authentication
{
    public class ApplicationDbContext:IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
    {
        public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options):base(options)
        {
        }

        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlite(@"Data source=test.db");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: See the same question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69275805/how-to-use-configuration-from-dotnet-6-minimal-api-in-entity-framework-core-cli#comment122628732_69275805, and my comment under "accepted answer". If you want to be safe, create and use a [design-time factory](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/cli/dbcontext-creation?tabs=dotnet-core-cli#from-a-design-time-factory) - the only reliable method not affected by framework changes and dedicated for EF Core design time tools. Also, note the link in the error message - it is the first place to look at before searching web.

Comment: I upgraded all the entity-framework-related to the "pre-release" versions (by checking on it in the Nuget manager), and the command worked.

Comment: Are you sure? Does it work if you remove `optionsBuilder.UseSqlite(@"Data source=test.db");` from `OnConfiguring` and put it here `AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlite(@"Data source=test.db")`. Which is the whole purpose of having constructor  with `DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options`. With the current code inside the `OnConfiguring` you are simply ignoring these options.

Comment: Anyway, since the question is apparently the same, redirecting it to the other thread.