# Configuring EF in ASP.NET Core 6 Program.cs

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, entity-framework-6

I'm asked to make an `ASP.NET Core 6 webAPI`, I have no prior experience with Microsoft stuff, I'm following MS Docs [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-mvc/intro?view=aspnetcore-6.0#register-the-schoolcontext) In the Docs they teach how to configure `EF` in a `Startup.cs` file with a `Main` method(they forgot to update the docs ?), which is not there in an `ASP.NET Core 6`, My `Program.cs` Doesn't have a `Main` method and looks like this:

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.

builder.Services.AddControllers();
// Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();

app.Run();
```

How to add the EF to `Program.cs` in this case ?

**EDIT:** and how to add the `CreateDbIfNotExist()` ([Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-mvc/intro?view=aspnetcore-6.0#code-try-12)) method while there is no class for it to reside in ?

Comment: It's hard to find unless you know what you're looking for, but there are samples of using EF Core with ASP.NET Core in the Razor Pages documentation. [Here's the relevant section](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-rp/intro?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio#programcs) about adding your `DbContext` to your registered services via `builder.Services.AddDbContext<T>()`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use configuration from dotnet 6 minimal API in Entity Framework Core cli tools](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69275805/1260204)

Comment: Not sue what you are looking for but see this if it helps https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/get-started/overview/first-app?tabs=netcore-cli

Comment: Somone at Microsoft is too lazy to update the documentation for EF Core on ASP.NET MVC Core https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-mvc/intro?view=aspnetcore-8.0, please use the link provided by @DM

Answer (score 6, accepted):

this is the code in asp.net core 6:

```
// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddControllers();
builder.Services.AddDbContext<"YOUR_DBCONTEXT">(option =>
    option.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString(CONNECTION_STRING)));
```

change YOUR_DBCONTEXT and CONNECTION_STRING with your data.